# Assembly Code CPUID leaf for virtualized container signatures detection?

Tags: docker, assembly, x86-64, virtualization, cpuid

Hello can you please help? Does anyone know what intel x86-x64 assembly code CPUID leaf detects if you are inside a virtualized container? The leaf to see the signatures?

Something Similar to the code I wrote here to run this it will detect if you are inside a virtual machine. Loading RAX with Leaf 0x40000000:0x400000010 will show the virtual machine signature with the help of the primary CPU.

Again, Docker containers do require the virtualization to be enabled in the bios so in theory you should be able to detect if your inside a container also with I/O, something similar to ref below.

My curent Professor has never worked with leafs like this for signature detections, can anyone help me find this it's not anywhere on Google?

[Example in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqvVX.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o3UI.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPX4m.png)

[Code Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxJ5h.png)

Ref:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1009458

What I am searching for:
CPUID leaf that shows docker signature

Comment: Has anyone used this leaf inside a container yet? I used it with a VMware machine it works, but I just had a thought, Intel and AMD reserved the leaf for all virtualization use, it may kick back a signature for Docker already. . .

Comment: I don't think Docker containers use virtualisation.

Comment: To run Docker you have to have virtualization enabled in the BIOS.